# How to configure a polymorphic Map relationship with EBean?

Tags: java, jpa, polymorphic-associations, ebean

I have seen examples of setting up Map association with EBean. Examples I've seen typically support a schema as below.

With such a schema, the JPA mapping of `Video` would have a property `public List<VideoMetadata> metadata;`.

How can I change this so that `metadata` is a `Map` instead of a `List`, for instance `public Map<String, String> metadata;`?

```sql
CREATE TABLE video (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE metadata (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  video_id UUID NOT NULL, -- this relationship is not polymorphic
  key VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

I have defined a polymorphic relationship between Metadata and Video (and Photo, and on...). A Video can have multiple metadata, as can a Photo.

The polymorphic relationship is configured with `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` and the "describable" is identified via a combination of `describable_type` and `describable_id`.

The database schema looks like this.

```sql
CREATE TABLE video (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE metadata (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  describable_id UUID NOT NULL, -- now we have polymorphism
  describable_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, -- now we have polymorphism
  key VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

And the models (in case it's relevant, I'm using Ebean)...

```java
package models;

import io.ebean.Model;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.UUID;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Video extends Model {

    @Id
    public UUID id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String title;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "describable", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<VideoMetadata> metadata;

}
```

```java
package models;

import io.ebean.Model;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name = "describable_type",
    discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
public abstract class Metadata extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String key;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String value;

}
```

```java
package models;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("video")
public class VideoMetadata extends Metadata {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Video describable;

}
```

```java
package models;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("photo")
public class ImageMetadata extends Metadata {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Photo describable;

}
```

Comment: JPA mapping of a `Map<String,String>` is visible in many documents on the internet, for example http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#one_many_map_join_simple_simple  Note that EBean simply uses JPA annotations and is NOT a JPA Provider.

Comment: @DN1 thanks for your response. Indeed it's covered well on the internet, but my case is more complex than typical examples because the association is polymorphic via InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE.